PDFKIT Python Changes Position of Content
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Report Card</title>
    <style>
 body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 12px; /* Reduced font size */
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px; /* Decreased padding */
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-bottom: 5px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 6px; /* Reduced padding */
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        .personal-details-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }

        .personal-details-column {
            width: 48%; /* Slightly reduced width */
            margin-bottom: 5px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        .single-heading {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 5px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        .signatures {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin-top: 10px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        .overall-marks table {
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 5px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        .overall-marks th, .overall-marks td {
            padding: 4px; /* Reduced padding */
        }

        .term-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }

        .term {
            width: 48%;
        }

        /* Additional styling */
        .term-heading {
            font-size: 16px; /* Reduced font size */
            margin-bottom: 5px; /* Decreased margin */
        }

        .overall-marks h4 {
            font-size: 12px; /* Reduced font size */
        }

        .academics-heading {
            margin-bottom: 0; /* Reduced margin */
        }

        @media print {
    body {transform: scale(.95);margin: none;}
    table {page-break-inside: avoid;}

    
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/utkarsh-rana.appspot.com/o/download.jpg?alt=media&amp;token=c2f5bd47-437b-46fc-b703-fd273002bbf4" alt="School Logo" width="69" height="39"> NATIONAL SCHOOL</h1>
        <h2>REPORT CARD</h2>
        <h3 class="single-heading">Personal Details</h3>
        <div class="personal-details-container">
            <div class="personal-details-column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <td>{{sid}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td>{{name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Father's Name</th>
                        <td>{{fname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Mother's Name</th>
                        <td>{{mname}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="personal-details-column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <td>{{class}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Section</th>
                        <td>{{section}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Roll No</th>
                        <td>{{roll}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td>{{address}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="single-heading">ACADEMICS</h3>
        <div class="term-container">
            <div class="term">
                <h4 class="term-heading">TERM I</h4>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Subjects</th>
                        <th>Subject Enrichment</th>
                        <th>Notebook</th>
                        <th>Periodic Test</th>
                        <th>Half Yearly</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>English</td>
                        <td>{{ense}}</td>
                        <td>{{ennb}}</td>
                        <td>{{enpt}}</td>
                        <td>{{enmain}}</td>
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hindi</td>
                        <td>{{hise}}</td>
                        <td>{{hinb}}</td>
                        <td>{{hipt}}</td>
                        <td>{{himain}}</td>
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Mathematics</td>
                        <td>{{mase}}</td>
                        <td>{{manb}}</td>
                        <td>{{mapt}}</td>
                        <td>{{scmain}}</td>
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Science</td>
                        <td>{{scse}}</td>
                        <td>{{scnb}}</td>
                        <td>{{scpt}}</td>
                        <td>{{scmain}}</td>
                        
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Social Science</td>
                        <td>{{sose}}</td>
                        <td>{{sonb}}</td>
                        <td>{{sopt}}</td>
                        <td>{{somain}}</td>
                        
                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Computer</td>
                        <td>{{cose}}</td>
                        <td>{{conb}}</td>
                        <td>{{copt}}</td>
                        <td>{{comain}}</td>
                        
                       
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Repeat for other subjects -->
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="term">
                <h4 class="term-heading">TERM II</h4>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        
                        <th>Subject Enrichment</th>
                        <th>Notebook</th>
                        <th>Periodic Test</th>
                        <th>Yearly</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ense2}}</td>
                        <td>{{ennb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{enpt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{enmain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{engrade}}</td>
                        <td>{{ent}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
       
                        <td>{{hise2}}</td>
                        <td>{{hinb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{hipt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{himain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{higrade}}</td>
                        <td>{{hit}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
       
                        <td>{{mase2}}</td>
                        <td>{{manb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{mapt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{scmain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{magrade}}</td>
                        <td>{{mat}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
       
                        <td>{{scse2}}</td>
                        <td>{{scnb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{scpt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{scmain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{scgrade}}</td>
                        <td>{{sct}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
       
                        <td>{{sose2}}</td>
                        <td>{{sonb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{sopt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{somain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{sograde}}</td>
                        <td>{{sot}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
       
                        <td>{{cose2}}</td>
                        <td>{{conb2}}</td>
                        <td>{{copt2}}</td>
                        <td>{{comain2}}</td>
                        <td>{{cograde}}</td>
                        <td>{{cot}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Repeat for other subjects -->
                    <tr class="totals-row">
                        <th colspan="5">Total</th>
                        <td>{{term2Total}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overall-marks">
            <table>
                <tr class="totals-row">
                    <th>Total Working Days</th>
                    <td colspan="3">{{totalWorkingDays}}</td>
                    <th>Total Present Days</th>
                    <td colspan="3">{{presentDays}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Overall Marks</th>
                    <td colspan="5">{{overallMarks}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Overall Grade</th>
                    <td colspan="5">{{overallGrade}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="signatures">
            <div>
                <h4>Principal's Signature</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Class Teacher's Signature</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Above is HTML template I'm trying to convert into pdf using python-pdfkit.
1.This is how template looks in web browser.


This is how the template looks after converting into pdf.

code used to convert html into pdf:-

import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('rp2.html','test.pdf')

Tried converting HTML template to pdf but PDFKIT changed the position and alignment of content from how it appeared on the web browser
